# Is there any functions for MapControl that allows a second map to stay consistent with the first map? IE: Zoom/Location

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm wondering if MapControl has a specific function that allows using two maps to stay consistent with each other. Specifically, I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the second map zoom and center location equal to the first map. First map would allow changes and second map would follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Uwp hasn’t provided such api to achieve this effect directly. It is recommended to do this via data binding.

Note that: Since a string can't be converted to a Geopoint, you can't specify a value for the Center property in XAML markup unless you use data binding.

Xaml code:

```
 <StackPanel >
        <Maps:MapControl  x:Name="MapControl1"
                          Center="{x:Bind CityCenter,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ZoomLevel="{x:Bind ZoomLevel ,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Height="300"
                          Width="500"                          
                          ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
                          TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"        
                          MapServiceToken="..">
        </Maps:MapControl>
        
        <Maps:MapControl  x:Name="MapControl2"  Height="300"
                          Width="500"                   
                          Center="{x:Bind CityCenter,Mode=OneWay}"                         
                          ZoomLevel="{x:Bind ZoomLevel ,Mode=OneWay}"
                          ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
                          TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"        
                          MapServiceToken=".."/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Geopoint cityCenter;
    private double zoomLevel;
    public Geopoint CityCenter
    {
        get { return cityCenter; }
        set { cityCenter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CityCenter");
        }
    }
    public double ZoomLevel{
        get { return zoomLevel; }
        set
        {
            zoomLevel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ZoomLevel");
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify a known location.
        BasicGeoposition cityPosition = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 47.604, Longitude = -122.329 };
        CityCenter = new Geopoint(cityPosition);
        ZoomLevel = 12;      
        MapControl1.LandmarksVisible = true;
    }
```

}